# Undefined action? Program prints out different values one after the other

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I didn't quite know how to describe the question -and whether there is any name for my error.

When i run the programme type some number e.g. 5 the tree.root->pocz is first 1 and later the weird number. Anyone know what's going on and how to repair it?

```
struct Node 
{

    int pocz;
    int kon;
    Node *left, *right, *up;
};

class AVL{

    public:
        Node *root;
        void initiate(){
            root = NULL;
        }
        bool insertNode(int poczPrz, int konPrz);
};

    AVL tree;

    //part of AVL insert function
   bool AVL::insertNode(int poczPrz, int konPrz){

        Node w; 
        w.pocz = poczPrz;
        w.kon = konPrz;
        Node *n = &w;

        Node *x = tree.root;
        Node *y, *z;
        y = n->left = n->right = NULL;

        while(x){
            if(x->pocz == n->pocz){
                delete n;
                return false;
            }
            y = x;
            x = (n->pocz < x->pocz) ? x->left : x->right;
        }

        if(!(n->up = y)){
            cout << "We leave the function here\n";
            tree.root = n;
            return true;
        }

        if(n->pocz < y->pocz) y->left = n;
        else y->right = n;
    }

int main()
{

    int n;  cin >> n;

    tree.initiate();
    tree.insertNode(1,n);
    cout <<"root->pocz: "<< tree.root->pocz <<endl;     //prints 1
    cout <<"root->pocz: "<< tree.root->pocz <<endl;     //now prints sth like 2306050

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines are causing the issue?

Comment: @user3142434 Your `insertNode` function fails to return a value at the end.  Thus the behavior of your program is undefined:  
`if(n->pocz < y->pocz) y->left = n; else y->right = n; }`  and then ... nothing is returned.

Comment: Never really used the debugger and I don't even know how to use one- my only way of finding errors is by cout-ing as much as possible.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In the example above we always leave the function after we cout << "We leave the function here\n"; But even if we add return false at the end of the function it still changes nothing- the error still remains

Comment: I'm not really a C++ guy, but it looks like the structure Node w is defined on the stack. Its memory would be freed when the insertNode methods ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that n points to w which is a local variable in the function insert. At the end of the function insert, w gets deleted automatically. And the pointer that is in the tree points to an empty location. At your first cout instruction, by chance, nothing did overwrite over the previous memory location of w. Therefore it prints 1. That memory location is then over written by something else (from the cout call) and therefore it prints garbage.

Now the solution, use Node *n = new Node; instead of setting it to &w.

Answer (score 0):

In `insertNode` your `w` object has automatic storage and `n` is a pointer to it. In the  call to that function, it will assign `tree.root = n;`. After the function returns the object is destroyed and the pointer `tree.root` is left dangling (points to deallocated memory). After that, dereferencing the dangling pointer such as `tree.root->pocz` will have undefined behaviour. You can fix that by allocating the Node dynamically.

Comment: Node *n = new Node();